# Save workbook on desired location calling Workbook.Close() function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to save my workbook on a desired location with `Workbook.Close()`
But the script show the error message

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'D://any/location/672EF510'.
>  There are several possible reasons:
>   • The file name or path does not exist.
>   • The file is being used by another program.
>   • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
>   At line:8 char:1
>   + $wb.Close($true,"D:/any/location/workbook.xlsx")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The code is here.

```
$wb.Close($true,"D:/any/location/workbook.xlsx")
```

I also tried `$wb.Close($true,"D://any//location//workbook.xlsx")`

Is there any solution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Trying $wb.Close($true,"workbook.xlsx") worked. But it saved under documents.

Comment: Why not use `Workbook.SaveAs()` ?

Comment: I'll try it now. Thanks.

Comment: Still not working. The stack trace is here The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
• Make sure the specified folder exists.
• Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
• Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
• Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.
At line:8 char:1
+ $wb.SaveAs("D:\\any\\location\\workbook.xlsx")

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `/`instead of `\`. In your question. Is this the same in your Script?

Comment: I also tried back slash '\', double back slashes '\\', forward slash with back slash'\/' and single forward slash'/'.